# Keycloak social login modifications

Tags: spring-boot, keycloak, idp, keycloak-spi

I am trying to customize the social login feature of keycloak. I want to perform following tasks when a new user is registered in keycloak using social login feature.

- Add some additional roles
- Persist some data in my database using REST endpoint.

Use case details: My web application allows different types of users to get registered. Based on what type of user is trying to get registered, i assign some specific roles and also persist data in my database. I want to make sure that user type information is not lost when the user gets registered using social login feature of keycloak.

Is this possible? What is the best approach to do this?

Comment: Where are your roles stored - Keycloak or, for example, in your DB?

Comment: I am using a spring boot service. Roles are evaluated based on user type in this service and then are assigned. So in short, i can have an endpoint on my spring boot service that can return required roles.